# html background color wont change

Tags: html, css, angularjs, background-color, styling

I'm trying to change the background color of a certain page. I tried setting the HTML as the background color, with important!, but it still doesn't work. Neither does setting the background color of *.

the bottom of the page looks like this and its what I'm trying to fix. I assume it's because I added a margin-bottom to the last container but I need it. Thanks for the help!

ALSO, seem to be having this issue on other pages as well.

[image]

```css
.bods {
  background-color: #555B6E !important;
  font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
  font-style: normal;
}

.container-1 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.container-2 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.container-3 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.paragraph-1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.paragraph-2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.paragraph-3 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}


/* .nav-grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-auto-columns: max-content;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    -ms-grid-rows: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;


} */


/* @media screen and (max-width: 479px){

} */

div.card-body.shadow.p-3.mb-5.rounded {
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  background-color: #CBC0D3 !important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #9b62b1 !important;
}

p {
  background-color: #9b62b1 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="bods">
  <br>
  <br>

  <br>

  <div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded">
    <h1 class="heading">
      Heading 1
    </h1>
    <p class="paragraph-1">Text 1</p>
  </div>


  <div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded">
    <h1 class="heading">
      Heading 2
    </h1>
    <p class="paragraph-2">Text 2</p>
  </div>


  <div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded">
    <h1 class="heading">
      Heading 3
    </h1>
    <p class="paragraph-3">Text 3</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what I understand is that you are not adding CSS classes at all for the color to HTML elements.

Comment: It looks like its working in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know more about your problem.

Classes "container-1, container-2, container-3" do not exist in html.
Other classes I can change background color.

[image]

Comment: sorry I forgot to add in the HTML tag back. I was experimenting removing it to see if it would work.

Comment: there is an empty space below this container which color does not get filler

Comment: Can you tell which class the space is under?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a class `.bods` in the body which overrides your `body` definition (classes take precedence over simple elements).

Furthermore, `.bods` has an `!important`, so you will need something like this to override it:

```
body.bods {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Or change the .bods definition if you have access to the file:

```
.bods {
  background-color: red !important;
  font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```css
body.bods {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.bods {
  background-color: #555B6E !important;
  font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
  font-style: normal;
}

.container-1 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.container-2 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.container-3 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #50354d!important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

.paragraph-1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.paragraph-2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.paragraph-3 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}


/* .nav-grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-auto-columns: max-content;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    -ms-grid-rows: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;


} */


/* @media screen and (max-width: 479px){

} */

div.card-body.shadow.p-3.mb-5.rounded {
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  background-color: #CBC0D3 !important;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 120px 75px 0px 50px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #9b62b1 !important;
}

p {
  background-color: #9b62b1 !important;
}
```

```html
<html><body class="bods"> <br><br><br><div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded"> <h1 class="heading"> Heading 1 </h1> <p class="paragraph-1">Text 1</p></div><div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded"> <h1 class="heading"> Heading 2 </h1> <p class="paragraph-2">Text 2</p></div><div class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded"> <h1 class="heading"> Heading 3 </h1> <p class="paragraph-3">Text 3</p></div></body></html>
```